# Is there a reliable way to programmatically determine that a window manager has fully initialized?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

I want to run a minimal X session with just a window manager and a single fullscreen program.  The obvious way to do this is by putting something like this in .xinitrc:

```
metacity & # this could be any window manager
exec my-fullscreen-app
```

But since these are launched in parallel, there's a bit of a race condition.  I don't want my app to appear before the window manager is ready, because then there will be a visible resizing of its window to fullscreen mode.  I want to make sure the window manager has finished initializing first.

The best I've come up with is something like this:

```
metacity &
while ! xprop -root | grep -q _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK
do
    sleep 0.1
done
sleep 0.3
exec my-fullscreen-app
```

But just because _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK has been set on the root window doesn't necessarily mean that the WM is truly ready, and the 0.3 second sleep after it is a kludge that might be serious overkill on some systems and might be totally inadequate on others.

So is there a better way to reliably sense that the window manager is fully initialized?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but isn't this a case where you don't need a window manager at all?

Comment: Karl, you do need a window manager in order to properly fullscreen your window.  Also, the app may launch other apps while it's running, which also require a running window manager to function properly. (I guess I did neglect to mention that part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, there's no way.

metacity in particular still has stuff left to do after setting the _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK property.

I think your approach is about the best you can do.

On the plus side, unless there are bugs, the race should not have any effects other than cosmetic ones. (i.e. things are shown that aren't in their final state)

To mitigate, you might want to set your window to fullscreen size manually before mapping it.
Then let the WM set the size after that.

Comment: That is a good point about setting it to the screen's size manually as well as using the fullscreen property -- I think that would eliminate most of my concern about seeing a fleeting glimpse of the window at a smaller size.

Comment: Here's another idea: I could have the app start with the window iconified, and then de-iconify the window (via EWMH, so it'll only work once the WM is responsive), in a loop, until I detect that it actually worked.  I guess this technically could get into a race condition if a user (or some other program) manually re-iconified the window very quickly, but assuming that corner case is very unlikely, I think this would work...

Comment: that would probably work, you'd have to properly set the WM_STATE and other properties yourself prior to initial map.

Comment: I decided against the iconification hack.  Just doesn't seem worth the added complexity. Also, the set-to-screen-size approach does not help, because Metacity responds with "Treating resize request of legacy application X as a fullscreen request" and it is subsequently impossible to leave fullscreen mode without changing the window size... once again, it just spirals into more hacks and complexity from there.  So I'm just going to maintain the simple/naive approach and not worry about it.